# windows bat file: undo NET USE

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a batch-file I use the following syntax to map a network drive:

NET USE N: \\someserver\somedirectory.

While this works fine, it also gives an error if the letter n is already used. Is it possible to suppress this error message?

Also, is there a way to unmap a network drive?

I imagine something like:

NET UNUSE N:

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After

```
NET USE N: \\somserver\somedirectory
```

to remove simply:

```
NET USE N: /DELETE
```

To test for an existing mapping you can;

```
IF NOT EXIST N:\. GOTO BLABLA
```

Comment: thanks, this is giving me a question: `There are open files and/or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to N:.
Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? (Y/N) [N]:` can this be forced to yes?

Comment: If it **is** ok do disconnect try `ECHO Y|NET USE N: /DELETE`

Comment: thanks, just to be precise the command is EXIST and not EXISTS

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if a drive is in use by running

```
net use N:
```

you'll get different return results `$?` in PowerShell and `%ERRORLEVEL%` in Batch.

If mapped $? will be `True` and `%ERRORLEVEL%` will be 0

To unmap, just do

```
net use N: /DELETE
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is:
IF NOT EXIST N:. NET USE N: \someserver\somedirectory